# How can I compute Expectation of Arbitrary Expressions over Random Variables?

Tags: probability-theory

Mathematica seems to be doing it: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/probability-and-statistics-solvers-and-properties/compute-the-expectation-of-an-expression.html

I'm interested in how can this be done algorithmically, without using numerical integration, etc.

E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]

E[if E1 then E2 else E3] = E[E1]E[E2] + (1-E[E1])E[E3]

But, how can I compute E[X > Y] as some function of properties of X and Y. If this cannot be done exactly, how can this be done approximately?

Comment: Why close this?

Comment: Does $E[X \gt Y]$ mean the expectation of an indicator variable that takes the value $1$ when $X \gt Y$ and $0$ otherwise? If so, then  it is $\Pr(X \gt Y)$

Answer (score 0):

Let$X$ be a random variable having a pdf f(x) over $x \in (x_1,x_2)$ for a continuous distribution.  Then the expectation of $g(X)$ is

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx\, g(x) \, f(x)$$

For a discrete distribution $f(k)$, $k \in \{0,1,...,K\}$, the expectation is

$$\sum_{k=0}^K g(k) f(k)$$

In the case of the first entry, a Poisson distribution is

$$f(k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}$$

where $K=\infty$, and if $g(k)=e^{2 k}$, we have the expected value being

$$e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{2 k} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^2 \lambda^k}{k!} = e^{\lambda e^2-\lambda}$$

as stated in the entry.

To compute $P(X>Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables, you would compute $E(X-Y \gt 0)$, where $X-Y$ is a normal-variate having mean $\mu_X-\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$.

Comment: How can I algorithmic-ally compute E[X > Y] where X and Y are Normal-variate?

Comment: You would compute $E(X-Y \gt 0)$, where $X-Y$ is a normal-variate having mean $\mu_X-\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$.

Comment: How can I symbolically/analytically/algorithmically compute P(X > 0) where X is normavariate?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2}$$  You typically end up looking these up in a table, expressing as an error function, or asking Mathematica to perform the integration.

Comment: And what if X and Y are arbitrary expressions over other random variables?

Comment: Gotta go case by case.  You can add expected values and variances, but that's about all you can say.

Comment: Actually, the thing is, I want a very fast way to compute approximate expectations of expressions of RVs. I have a grammar defined. All other cases like plus, minus, if-then-else are dealt with, i.e. I have defined a recursive function, that computes expectation of the expression using expectation of subexpressions. The only case left is GreaterThan. So, I'm wondering if there is a theoretically sound way to approximate E[X > Y] as some function of E[X], E[Y], or other moments of X and Y. 

Is there some analogy of Taylor series for RVs ?